# how to .find() more than one array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't know if the title makes sense, if it does hurray. Let me explain. In my app I have a barcode scanner using react native camera. This barcode scanner scans the barcode and returns the name, produkt, id or whatever.
Right now it's set up for displaying the id(barcode number) if the barcode number is the same as the id, it returns an alert with the barcode number. But how can I make it return more than the id? Like id and name within the same alert.

```
{
    id: '5000112637939',
    name: 'Coca Cola Zero',
    company: 'COCA-COLA',
  },
```

.

```
checkBarcode(scanResult) {
    const product = DataBase.find((codeMetadata) => {
      return codeMetadata.id === scanResult.data;
    });

    if (product) {
      alert(product.id);
    } else {
      alert('text text text text error text');
    }
```

Comment: `alert(product.id + ' ' + product.name)`? I'm not sure I understand the desired result. You already have the whole product within the `product` variable, is there something else you need?

Comment: `find` returns the whole element found, that part is already working. Your alert is what needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first item in the array that it finds or undefined.

You have the product object in your variable so you can do it like this.

```
checkBarcode(scanResult) {
    const product = DataBase.find((codeMetadata) => {
      return codeMetadata.id === scanResult.data;
    });

    if (product) {
      alert(product.id + ': ' + product.name);
    } else {
      alert('Product not found');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert whole object to text or one by one like previous answer.

```
alert(
   Object.entries(product).reduce((r,[key,value])=>`${r}\n${key}:${value}`,'')
);
```